# CSS selecting children, need bypass?

Tags: html, css, children

I dont know how to solve please help.

I have a css property apply to all after first ul

```
 .a ul ul {
    display:none;
}
```

If the html is below, the css works fine.

```
<section class="a">
    <ul>
      <li>  
        <ul> </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
</section>
```

However, if the html is

```
<section class="a">
  <ul>
    <li> <div> </div> 
      <ul> </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

The css will not pass through the `div` tag.

Please advance a way to solve, thank you very much.

**Question**

Is CSS able to find the child element in this situation?

Comment: Are you sure the CSS is working at all? Your example shows a CSS class of .A (uppercase A) but in your HTML you refer to it as "a" (lowercase a). CSS class names are case sensitive.

Comment: OK, so now the case of the CSS class is correct ... What is it you are trying to achieve? Is it that you want the child ul to be hidden?

Comment: yes, I want all ul after first ul be hidden

Comment: How can the CSS not pass through the `div`? What do you even mean by that?

Comment: If I insert tag, not only div, after li and before ul, then css property will not apply the next ul corretly

Comment: If any of the below answers presented a solution to your question, please accept their answer by clicking on the check mark beside their answer. This will help future users searching for an answer to the same question. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, you want to use the > selector like this:

```
.a ul > ul {
    display:none;
}
```

The selector X > Y selects the children of type Y from type X

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Hope this helps

Nathan

Comment: The selector `ul > ul` doesn't make sense. The only kind of child a `ul` can have is `li`. You probably meant `li > ul` or `ul > li > ul`.

Comment: Thank you very much. however, that will not work.....if use that way, u need to write ul>li>ul

Comment: Good point BoltClock. I was just going on the OP's original CSS. ul > li > ul is better

Answer (score 1):

If you truly want it to be "all hidden after the first" then you would use a css pseudo class like #26 from [here (30 CSS selectors you must memorize)](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize/)

```
.a ul {display:none;}
.a ul:first-child {display:block;}
```

The above is a GREAT resource that should be bookmarked for everyone using CSS.